# Why doesn't it throw OverFlow Exception?

Tags: c#, .net

Sample 1

```
int a = Int32.MinValue;
int b = -a;
Console.WriteLine("a={0}",a);
Console.WriteLine("b={0}", b);
```

Result

```
a=-2147483648
b=-2147483648
```

Sample 2

```
int a = Int32.MinValue;
int b = a-1;
Console.WriteLine("a={0}",a);
Console.WriteLine("b={0}", b);
```

Result

```
a=-2147483648
b=2147483647
```

In two samples: why doesn't  it throw overflow exception. When I tried these samples in java environment,  I got same results. Is there anyone who can explain this situation?

Comment: This is not `Java`. Please use valid tags only.

Comment: Try wrapping the .Net code in a `checked{}` block?

Comment: He said he *"tried these samples in java environment"*. Anyway he should add the Java code if he did, not just the C# code.

Comment: You'll get an overflow error if you put it into `checked` block: `checked {int b = -a ...}`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h25wtyxf.aspx